# Javascript can't change input value

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

I'm trying to set a random number as value for an ons-input (signup_txtCodigo), but whenever I try to push the page it just shows me the alert that I put it to check the random and stays there.
This is the page template:

```
<!--External user register-->
        <template id="signup.html">
            <ons-page id="login-page" modifier="full_bg">
                <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent">
                    <div class="center" style="font-size:150%;color:#f0f0f0">Estacionamiento UdeG</div>
                    <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Volver</ons-back-button></div>
                </ons-toolbar>
                <div align="center">
                    <br><img src="https://quimicabasicacucei.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/logo-udg.png?w=316" alt="logo" height=250px><br>
                    <p style="color:#f0f0f0">Registrar usuario</p>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color:#f0f0f0">Código:</td>
                            <td><div contenteditable><ons-input input-id="signup_txtCodigo" type="text" modifier="underbar" readonly></ons-input></div></td>  //this is the input I'm trying to change
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color:#f0f0f0">Nombre:</td>
                            <td><ons-input input-id="signup_txtNombre" type="text" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Nombre"></ons-input></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color:#f0f0f0">Placa:</td>
                            <td><ons-input input-id="signup_txtPlaca" type="text" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Ej. A1B-2C3" maxlength="7"></ons-input></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color:#f0f0f0">Teléfono:</td>
                            <td><ons-input input-id="signup_txtTelefono" type="text" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Teléfono" maxlength="10"></ons-input></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color:#f0f0f0">Contraseña:</td>
                            <td><ons-input input-id="signup_txtPassword" type="password" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Contraseña" maxlength="10"></ons-input></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><br>
                    <ons-button onclick="signup()" modifier="cta">Enviar</ons-button>
                    <ons-button onclick="cleanSignUp()" >Limpiar</ons-button><br><br>
                </div>
            </ons-page>
        </template>
```

This is the function that should asign the value to the input and push the page:

```
//load signup page
        function externalUserPage(){
            var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999999) + 111111111);
            alert(random);
            document.getElementById("signup_txtCodigo").value = random
            document.querySelector('#myNavigator').pushPage('signup.html', {data: {title: 'signup'}});
        }
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are using [The Content Template element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) and you have to remove the `dot` in the `id`.

so change

```
<template id="signup.html">
```

to

```
<template id="signuphtml">
```

you can access the content of the template like this

```
var content = document.querySelector('template#signuphtml').content;
```

to access you element use [document.importNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode)

```
var clone = document.importNode(content, true);
var signup_txtCodigo = clone.querySelector("[input-id='signup_txtCodigo']");
```

now you can fill it using [The textContent property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

here an illustration

```js
//load signup page
        (function externalUserPage(){
            var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999999) + 111111111);
            alert(random);
      
            var content = document.querySelector('template#signuphtml').content;
    
var clone = document.importNode(content, true);
    var signup_txtCodigo = clone.querySelector("[input-id='signup_txtCodigo']");
    signup_txtCodigo.innerHTML = random;
  //document.getElementById("signup_txtCodigo").value = random
          console.log(signup_txtCodigo);  document.querySelector('#myNavigator').pushPage('signup.html', {data: {title: 'signup'}});
        })();
```

```html
<!--External user register-->
        <template id="signuphtml">
            <ons-page id="login-page" modifier="full_bg">
                <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent">
                    <div class="center" style="font-size:150%;color:#f0f0f0">Estacionamiento UdeG</div>
                    <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Volver</ons-back-button></div>
                </ons-toolbar>
                <div align="center">
                    <br><img src="https://quimicabasicacucei.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/logo-udg.png?w=316" alt="logo" height=250px><br>
                    <p style="color:#f0f0f0">Registrar usuario</p>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color:#f0f0f0">Código:</td>
                            <td><div contenteditable><ons-input input-id="signup_txtCodigo" type="text" modifier="underbar" readonly></ons-input></div></td>  //this is the input I'm trying to change
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color:#f0f0f0">Nombre:</td>
                            <td><ons-input input-id="signup_txtNombre" type="text" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Nombre"></ons-input></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color:#f0f0f0">Placa:</td>
                            <td><ons-input input-id="signup_txtPlaca" type="text" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Ej. A1B-2C3" maxlength="7"></ons-input></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color:#f0f0f0">Teléfono:</td>
                            <td><ons-input input-id="signup_txtTelefono" type="text" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Teléfono" maxlength="10"></ons-input></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color:#f0f0f0">Contraseña:</td>
                            <td><ons-input input-id="signup_txtPassword" type="password" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Contraseña" maxlength="10"></ons-input></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><br>
                    <ons-button onclick="signup()" modifier="cta">Enviar</ons-button>
                    <ons-button onclick="cleanSignUp()" >Limpiar</ons-button><br><br>
                </div>
            </ons-page>
        </template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it does access to the template, but it only does it when I remove the "document.getElementById("signup_txtCodigo").value = random" instruction... That's the one giving me problems, and I can't find why.

Comment: see the update how to access your element using `document.importNode` and you may want to change `document.querySelector('#myNavigator').pushPage`  to `$scope.nav.pushPage` since `pushPage` is no vanilla.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change a field marked as `readonly`, you should use `disabled`

```
<ons-input input-id="signup_txtCodigo" type="text" modifier="underbar" disabled></ons-input>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment
It didn't work either. Also I have another readonly input that works well with the same instruction. This is the only one that doesn't change its value.

Answer (score 0):

In order to assign value to that input please check your function if it got call or you wrote it in document.ready.

for my idea this example should be work:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999999) + 111111111);
     document.getElementById("signup_txtCodigo").value = random;
});
```

Reference link : [Input Text value Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value2)

Answer (score 0):

Just change `input-id="signup_txtCodigo"` to `id="signup_txtCodigo"`

I did a quick google search, but from what I can gather, `input-id` is not a valid OnSen element attribute, therefore you cannot select it by Id by conventional JavaScript means.